# Text is blocked by element on Html page when used on mobile device

Tags: html, css

I am making a website and have run into a problem. When i use it on desktop, all dividers have text which is clear and readable. . (Look Below):

[image]

However, when used on a mobile device the headers (Example Header) are underneath the divider element. This is fustrating as it not only blocks the text rendering it unreadable, but also makes it look bad. I was wondering if i could have some help.

On Mobile device (I have added rings around the problems):

[image]

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">
<link rel='shorcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='circle.ico' />
</head>
<body>

<title>Home</title>

<div class="header">
  <h3 class="logo" id='logo'>Logo</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
  <label for="chk" class="show-menu-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
  </label>

  <ul class="menu" id='navbar'>
    <a href="#section1">Home</a>
    <a href="#section2">About</a>
    <a href="#">Calendar</a>
    <a href="#">News</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <label for="chk" class="hide-menu-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </label>
  </ul>
</div>

<style>
body {
  margin:0px;
}
.colour-block {
  background:#34495e;
  width:60%;
  padding:7% 20% 10% 20%;
  color:#fff;
}
.white-block {
  background:#fff;
  width:60%;
  padding:7% 20% 10% 20%;
  color:#823A9C;
}
h1 {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:80px;
  font-family:'wire one', serif;
  font-weight:normal;
}
p {
  font-size:20px;
  font-family:'Raleway', serif;
}


/*------------------*/
/*  SKEW CLOCKWISE  */
/*------------------*/
.skew-cc{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #34495e 49%, #fff 50%),    linear-gradient(-50deg, #ffffff 16px, #000 0);
}


/*-------------------------*/
/* SKEW COUNTER CLOCKWISE  */
/*-------------------------*/
.skew-c{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, #fff 49%, #34495e 50%);
}
</style>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Wire+One|Raleway:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


**THIS IS WHERE I HAVE DONE THE DIVIDERS**
<div class="skew-c"></div>
<div class="colour-block">
  <h1>Example Header</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
</div>
<div class="skew-cc"></div>
<div class="white-block">
  <h1>Example Header</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
</div>
<div class="skew-c"></div>
<div class="colour-block">
  <h1>Example Header</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
</div>

<div class="content">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use media queries to rais the margin-top for the first etxt element for mobile view.

Comment: i am sort of new to html and css... how would i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by giving `padding-top` for heading for mobile

like this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .colour-block h1, .white-block h1{ padding-top: 40px;}
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">
<link rel='shorcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='circle.ico' />
</head>
<body>

<title>Home</title>

<div class="header">
  <h3 class="logo" id='logo'>Logo</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
  <label for="chk" class="show-menu-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
  </label>

  <ul class="menu" id='navbar'>
    <a href="#section1">Home</a>
    <a href="#section2">About</a>
    <a href="#">Calendar</a>
    <a href="#">News</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <label for="chk" class="hide-menu-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </label>
  </ul>
</div>

<style>
body {
  margin:0px;
}
.colour-block {
  background:#34495e;
  width:60%;
  padding:7% 20% 10% 20%;
  color:#fff;
}
.white-block {
  background:#fff;
  width:60%;
  padding:7% 20% 10% 20%;
  color:#823A9C;
}
h1 {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:80px;
  font-family:'wire one', serif;
  font-weight:normal;
  
}
p {
  font-size:20px;
  font-family:'Raleway', serif;
}


/*------------------*/
/*  SKEW CLOCKWISE  */
/*------------------*/
.skew-cc{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #34495e 49%, #fff 50%),    linear-gradient(-50deg, #ffffff 16px, #000 0);
}


/*-------------------------*/
/* SKEW COUNTER CLOCKWISE  */
/*-------------------------*/
.skew-c{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, #fff 49%, #34495e 50%);
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
   .colour-block h1,.white-block h1{ padding-top: 40px;}
  }
</style>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Wire+One|Raleway:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


**THIS IS WHERE I HAVE DONE THE DIVIDERS**
<div class="skew-c"></div>
<div class="colour-block">
  <h1>Example Header</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
</div>
<div class="skew-cc"></div>
<div class="white-block">
  <h1>Example Header</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
</div>
<div class="skew-c"></div>
<div class="colour-block">
  <h1>Example Header</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
</div>

<div class="content">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```